# Sometimes the Hand tool of Acrobat Reader has an arrow?

Tags: adobe-acrobat, pdf-reader

Sometimes, in Adobe Acrobat Reader of PDF reader, the hand tool has an arrow on it and in this condition, it will jump a page or a half ahead if clicked.

How to configure that so the hand tool can only hold and release?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just fixed, the setting is:

> “Edit -> Preferences -> General -> Make Hand Tool Read Articles”

Uncheck this item.

Worked on Adobe Acrobat Reader DC 19.021.20061 .